# Как объеденить значения несколько одинаковых строк в одну (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть несколько строк в таблице, которые разделены датами, но с одинаковыми именами 
table_date name 
2014-01-01 name1 
2014-02-01 name1 
2014-03-01 name1 
2014-04-01 name2 
2014-05-01 name2

Как создать запрос, чтобы показало в виде:
table_date name 
2014-01-01 name1
2014-04-01 name2

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл вот такой ответ вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102283/how-to-concat-many-rows-into-one-string-in-sql-server-2008), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into):

```sql
DECLARE @temp TABLE (name NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (name)
VALUES ('kim'),('lee'),('park'),('cho')

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + name
    FROM @temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```